# How to connect SDB with Oracle database?

Tags: java, jena

I want to connect with Oracle databse using SDB Jena, but I don't know how can i do that(I found tutorial for mysql but for Oracle is hard to found anything usefull).

Comment: Are you trying directly from java, or using a configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](http://incubator.apache.org/jena/documentation/sdb/javaapi.html#in_java_code) (with a little twist) try:

```
StoreDesc storeDesc = new StoreDesc(LayoutType.LayoutTripleNodesHash,
                                   DatabaseType.Index) ;
JDBC.loadDriverOracle() ;
String jdbcURL = "jdbc:....oracle connection...";
SDBConnection conn = new SDBConnection(jdbcURL, username, password) ;
Store store = SDBFactory.connectStore(conn, storeDesc) ;
```

Working out the jdbc url for oracle is all you need. Bit fiddly, but not SDB specific: there's plenty of help out there.